# easyPHP-DevServer 13.1 apache unexpected error

Tags: apache, easyphp

I'm running Win 8.1 for 64 bit processor and installed easyPHP-DevServer 13.1 VC11 and MySQL 5.6.12 update.I'm trying to run it locally on my laptop.  When I start easyPHP MySQL runs but apache log gives "unexpected error" and stops. I also get "MSVCR110.dll" is missing error. I installed the missing .dll but when I start easyPHP it still can't find it the .dll. The link for downloading the missing MSVCR110.dll is

http://search.microsoft.com/en-us/DownloadResults.aspx?rf=sp&q=microsoft%20visual%20c%2B%2B%202010%20sp1%20redistributable%20package

I learned on another forum to use the 2010 package not the 2012.
I need an answer for getting easyPHP to find the .dll and how to get apache running.

Answer (score 11):

I'll take a guess and say that you need to download the x86 version of the Visual Studio redistributable.  Even though I'm running a 64 bit machine, only the x86 version of the redistributable worked for me (I only tried VS 2012).

After that, Apache ran with no further problems.

Comment: This worked for me too.  Here's the direct link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: yup it worked for me too...this might be the problem due to installation of easyphp on x64 machine.

Comment: great , it worked for me, however i already closed stack overflow tab on my browser i reopened it  and come back her to add thumb up for the the solution

Answer (score 0):

Copy the folder of Apache (apache-tomcat-7.0.54) to the directory C:\Program Files (x86) and then just install again EasyPHP and it works. (I have the same problem and it's resolved by this method.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... My solutions is download Microsoft movie maker. This solutions always work for me...

**Here is a URL** http://windows.microsoft.com/cs-cz/windows/movie-maker

But be careful, if u will install from windows essentials 2012, **u must select 2nd choice**. Like "Select programs, will be install" and **select only pictures and movie maker**